# Eclipse and running Android application

Tags: android, eclipse

I recreated a whole new project and when I try to run the application I get `Your project contains error(s), please fix them before running your application.`

I'm not too sure if this just started after I updated my eclipse but I did the following but to no avail:

1. Clean the project.
2. Delete `.android` folder.
3. Restart Eclipse.

My previous android projects are still running ok. Anyone has anymore ideas?

UPDATE: As I updated my plugin before, you have to update the sdk manager after. This solved the problem!

Comment: One method is to open problems pane and delete all entries in it

Comment: You probably only updated your Eclipse-plugin. Try updating your Android SDK Manager aswell.

Comment: Arslan was right. You had to update the SDK Manager as well. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse is usually pretty good at detecting / reporting problems - so there may very well be a genuine problem in your project.

Have a look in the Problems pane (it's usually a tab at the bottom of the pre-canned Perspectives - but you might have to do Window / Show View / Problems) which will normally show you where the error(s) are and what they are - usually even down to the file.

There is one particular build problem (I can't find the link right now) where Eclipse gets confused, and the solution is to delete the problem item in the Problem pane. So if the Problem pane doesn't direct you to the error, you could try that. [That is what ingsaurabh above is referring to - but I would make sure you do not have  a genuine error first before deleting problem reports - which will only come back in that case.]

Comment: That's the thing, the project was created from scratch. As in I just created a project then I try to run it. No additions or anything. Reading the logs did not say much either. :(

Comment: @Maurice Can you specify what the error was, following what Torid said? It might be specific problem with the code if not the buildpath and such.

Comment: currently updating through SDK Manager. and i deleted all the problems so I dun think I can trace it anymore. :(